# Attempt to read from field 'int android.media.CamcorderProfile.fileFormat' on a null object reference

Tags: android, video, camera, video-recording

I'm recording video by using Custom camera on Nexus 7 2012 and get this issue while the other devices, like Zenfone 2, Galaxy S3, S6, HTC One M7, Oppo N1, Sony Xperia M4 ... worked perfectly.

```
public static boolean prepareVideoRecorder(Context mContext, int mode) {
    // Should release before use new Preview for Recording Video mode
    CustomCamera.releaseCamera();

    // Initialize camera
    CustomCamera.mCamera = CustomCamera.getCameraInstance(mode);

    CustomCamera.mCamera.startPreview();

    // Set orientation display
    setCameraDisplayOrientation((Activity) mContext, mode);

    // Should release before use new Preview for Recording Video mode
    CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();

    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    CustomCamera.mCamera.unlock();
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setCamera(CustomCamera.mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    // todo NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.media.CamcorderProfile.fileFormat' on a null object reference
    //     

   // returned true value, go inside
   if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(current_camera_id, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW)) {
    // CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW) RETURNED NULL VALUE, SO I CAN NOT SET PROFILE     
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

    // Step 4: Set output file - pass False value to indicate choose Video mode
    RECORDED_FILE_PATH = getOutputMediaFile(mContext, false).toString();
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(RECORDED_FILE_PATH);

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    /**
     * Define Orientation of image in here,
     * if in portrait mode, use value = 90,
     * if in landscape mode, use value = 0
     */
    if (current_camera_id == define.Camera.CAMERA_BACK)
        // Back Camera
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder = Utils.rotateBackVideo(CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder);
    else
        // Front Camera
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder = Utils.rotateFrontVideo(CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder);

    // Set preview display to refresh current screen
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

These permissions I set :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>

<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What I want is make it can record video on Nexus 7 2012.

People who know,

Please tell me how to fix.

Thank you,

p/s : If I remove the `setProfile()` line I get the other exception and can not record video:

```
07-31 14:33:39.936  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload E/MediaRecorder﹕ setOutputFile called in an invalid state(2)
07-31 14:33:39.942  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-31 14:33:39.950  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaRecorder._setOutputFile(Native Method)
07-31 14:33:39.950  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:740)
07-31 14:33:39.950  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at ui.fragment.camera.CameraPreviewFragment.prepareVideoRecorder(CameraPreviewFragment.java:533)
07-31 14:33:39.950  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at ui.fragment.camera.CameraPreviewFragment.onClick(CameraPreviewFragment.java:223)
07-31 14:33:39.950  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
07-31 14:33:39.951  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
07-31 14:33:39.951  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-31 14:33:39.951  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-31 14:33:39.951  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-31 14:33:39.951  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-31 14:33:39.951  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-31 14:33:39.951  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-31 14:33:39.952  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 07-31 14:33:39.952  25960-25960/com.panasonic_Upload W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the camera id when calling get(), exactly the same as you do when you call hasProfile(). Otherwise it will take the profile from the first back camera it founds.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#pubmethods

The Nexus 7 2012 crashes because it doesn't have a back camera.

You need to do this instead:

`CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(current_camera_id, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));`